# C function not calculating properly

Tags: c, function, pointers

In my function when I set `*area = 2` or to any other int, my program works as intended. For some reason I cannot calculate the length by the width and have it out put properly, all I get are 0's. What am I missing? Is it something in the call? Also is `%f` an appropriate conversion for `double` or is there something better to use? My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void area_perimeter(double width, double length, double *area, double *perimeter);

    int main(){

            double width, length, are, peri;

            printf("Enter the width of the rectangle: ");
            scanf("%f",&width);

            printf("Enter the length of the rectangle: ");
            scanf("%f",&length);

            area_perimeter(width, length, &are, &peri);

            printf("The area of the rectangle is: %f\n",are);
            printf("The perimeter of the rectangle is: %f\n",peri);

            return 0;
    } 

    void area_perimeter(double width, double length, double *area, double *perimeter){

            *area = length * width;

            *perimeter = (*area * 2);

    }
```

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* by passing a pointer to object having wrong type: `%f` in `scanf()` callls for `float*`, but you passed `double*`. Use `%lf` to read `double`.

Comment: Thank you that solved both of my questions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by passing a pointer to object having wrong type: `%f` in `scanf()`callls for `float*`, but you passed `double*`. Use `%lf` to read double.

Using `%f` in `printf()` to print `double` is good. C99 compiler will also accept `%lf`.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void area_perimeter(double width, double length, double *area, double *perimeter);

int main(void){

        double width, length, are, peri;

        printf("Enter the width of the rectangle: ");
        if (scanf("%lf",&width) != 1) {
                fputs("read error width\n", stderr);
                return 1;
        }

        printf("Enter the length of the rectangle: ");
        if (scanf("%lf",&length) != 1) {
                fputs("read error length\n", stderr);
                return 1;
        }

        area_perimeter(width, length, &are, &peri);

        printf("The area of the rectangle is: %f\n",are);
        printf("The perimeter of the rectangle is: %f\n",peri);

        return 0;
} 

void area_perimeter(double width, double length, double *area, double *perimeter){

        *area = length * width;

        *perimeter = (*area * 2);

}
```